# Log every time a sheet is protected or unprotected in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, logging, protected

I'm looking for a way to write into another sheet in excel, every time someone either protects or unprotects the sheet in my Workbook. I want it to log whether it was protected or unprotected and the time beside it. Thanks!

Right now I have the following code for protecting or unprotecting the sheet with a more user friendly button:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Calendar").ProtectContents = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    MsgBox "Sheet unprotected"
    Exit Sub
End If

ActiveSheet.Protect ("password")
MsgBox "Calendar has been protected"
```

Comment: your code has a loop for all sheets, and seems to unprotect all sheets in that loop (but it only unprotects the active sheet, not all sheets), and then protects the active sheet again ??? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Which sheet do you intend to unprotect?

Comment: I didn't realize this, I was intending to unprotect just "Calendar" which is working fine, because I only have the one sheet protected.

Comment: I have just fixed this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Toggle and Log Worksheet Protection

- The code only logs the protection when using the button (which has `toggleWorksheetProtection_Click` assigned to it) or when running `toggleWorksheetProtection_Click` from `VBE`.
- Copy the complete code into a standard module (e.g. `Module11`).
- Adjust the values of the five **const**ants.
- `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook containing this code.
- Additionally adjust the date format in `writeLogRow`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub toggleWorksheetProtection_Click()
    ' Constants
    Const srcName As String = "Calendar"
    Const tgtName As String = "Log"
    Const tgtCol As Variant = 1
    Const msgProtect As String = "Sheet protected."
    Const msgUnProtect As String = "Sheet unprotected."
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' Other Variables
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = wb.Worksheets(tgtName)
    Dim msg As String
    ' Protection
    If src.ProtectContents Then
        src.Unprotect: msg = msgUnProtect
    Else
        src.Protect: msg = msgProtect
    End If
    ' Log
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = getEmptyCell(tgt, tgtCol)
    writeLogRow cel, msg

End Sub

Function getEmptyCell(Sheet As Worksheet, ByVal writeColumn As Variant)
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = Sheet.Columns(writeColumn).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If Not cel Is Nothing Then
        Set cel = cel.Offset(1)
    Else
        Set cel = Sheet.Cells(1, writeColumn)
    End If
    Set getEmptyCell = cel
End Function

Sub writeLogRow(logRange As Range, ByVal logMessage As String)
    Dim logDate As Date: logDate = Now
    logRange.Value = logDate
    logRange.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss (ddd)"
    logRange.Offset(, 1).Value = logMessage
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel VBA does not have an event that can detect if a sheet is being protected/unprotected.

Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: I have my own custom button for Protecting or Unprotecting the sheet so I could add it as a function there, it can detect whether it is being protected or unprotected. I would just need a function I suppose to log the time in a sheet.

Comment: So that's easy, then. But you won't be able to prevent the user from using the ribbon command to unprotect/protect and that will not trigger your code.

Comment: Thats ok with me, not ideal but it is what it is

Comment: So, is your question answered? Or are you asking how to write a time stamp into a cell? That has been asked and answered 1000 times already

Comment: I'm looking for a way to write to a different sheet, in the newest empty cell the time stamp and a message beside it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216176/discussion-between-jacob-and-teylyn).

Answer (score 0):

A google would have landed you here: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/43816-unprotect-worksheet-event/, the author even gives you a sample:
https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/core/index.php?attachment/1082834-52719-xls/

> This is not 100% fool proof as the eventhandler can not tell when a user Cancels the protect/unprotect dialog.

**This workbook**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    StartEventListiner False

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    StartEventListiner True

End Sub
```

**Module**

```
Option Explicit
Public g_clsEvnt As CProtectEvt

Public Sub StartEventListiner(Action As Boolean)

    If Action Then
        Set g_clsEvnt = New CProtectEvt
    Else
        Set g_clsEvnt = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

**Class**

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cbbProtect As CommandBarButton

Private Sub m_ProtectControls(State As Boolean)

    Dim objX As OLEObject

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each objX In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        objX.Object.Enabled = State
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub cbbProtect_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)

    m_ProtectControls (InStr(1, Ctrl.Caption, "Un&protect", vbTextCompare) > 0)

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    On Error Resume Next

    ' hook into Tools > Protection > Protect Sheet event
    Set cbbProtect = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(msoControlButton, ID:=893)

End Sub
```